# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' in Window Setup for react-native run-android

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT2Vl.png)

Not able to get pass this error. Checked my JAVA_HOME path and ANDROID_HOME path. Still not able to figure it out. I checked other solutions but of no help till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a gradle clean using the following commands
`cd android` 
`.\gradlew clean`
`cd ..`
`react-native run-android`

Comment: should use forward slash, `./gradlew clean`

Comment: If you are in windows, use `.\gradlew`. If in Linux or Mac, use `./gradlew`